# error while reading file into sqlite3

Tags: sqlite

I am a newbie to sqlite3.
I have some files which contain a .db file and also another file which contains the definition s of many tables.  I try to open with notepad and see that it has create table definitions of many files.
I am trying to read them in sqlite3 in linux.
I try to use .read FILENAME after which I try to see the tables by giving .tables command.
I cant see them.

Is there a way I need to source the file or execute.
Thanks for your help in advance

Comment: Show the exact sequence of commands that you have been using.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't done anything with SQLite in a long time, but when I did work with it I used a Firefox extension that made it easy.

Check out SQLite Manager to open the DB file:

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/sqlite-manager/

Answer (score 0):

`.read FILENAME` already executes the sql script in the FILENAME. Check if your `.db` file is writable and/or if the sql contained your file is correct.